# How To Count a Trained Classifiers Using Tensorflow and OpenCV For Traffic Count?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection

New to Tensorflow and its Object Detection API but looking at improving a project I am working on. So far I've basically trained two classifiers (person and cars) and I am able to count the number of times these two classifiers show up given a image. However, my main goal is to detect the traffic count of pedestrians and cars on a given intersection using a video. I have a working prototype that gets a video using OpenCV and starts counting the detected objects (classes) from the trained model, but it only counts the objects in that frame. It is also really finicky and looses the tracked object easily because it runs really slow. I am using Faster RCNN because I want a precise count but I feel this is slowing down the video. So I am having two problems:

1. Passing a video to the script runs it at 2fps, so how can I improve that? Thinking of a queue pipeline.
2. How can I count unique instances of each object, not just the objects shown in the frame? Right now I can only count objects in the frame but not total objects that have crossed by.

I've looked at using a Region Of Interest approach but the implementation that I've seen working is bi-directional I am looking for something more versatile and entirely machine-drive.

I might be thinking on this entirely wrong, so any guidance is greatly appreciated.